# Unichar not working properly in POWER BI DAX query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am facing an issue with the output of the below DAX query:

```
Health Indicator =
SWITCH (
    Projects1[Status],
    "Critical", UNICHAR ( 128308 ),
    "Watch Closely", UNICHAR ( 128993 ),
    "On track", UNICHAR ( 128994 )
)
```

In the report only for Critical status health indicator is showing a red circle. For others, it is showing a blank square. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

I have researched Microsoft Community forums and found this is a bug. I tried the workaround query provided them as below but no luck:

```
Health Indicator =
SWITCH (
    Projects1[Status],
    "Critical", UNICHAR ( 128308 ) & " ",
    "Watch Closely", UNICHAR ( 128993 ) & " ",
    "On track", UNICHAR ( 128994 ) & " "
)
```

Can someone please point out the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce this. Do you get the same thing if you replace `Projects1[Status]` with `CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Projects1[Status] ) )`?

Comment: You have no `else` clause, [add one to see if it's falling through](https://dax.guide/switch/).  Or you could use [conditional formatting, which has the same icons](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-august-2019-feature-summary/#iconStyles)